# Fixing displacement apparently originated from image extent

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am having problems with misalignment since. since I started to use GEE. I think I know what's wrong, but I don't know how to fix.

```
var amz18 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/trasegis/amazonia_pasture_2018')
var pasture = ee.Image();
for (var yr= 2001; yr <= 2018; yr = yr + 1) {
var pasture = pasture.addBands(ee.Image('users/vieiramesquita/PASTAGEM3/pasture_lapig_'+yr).remap([0,15],[0,1]).rename('pasture_'+yr));
}

Map.addLayer(pasture.select('pasture_2017'),{min:0,max:1},'raster2017') // example of a band without displacement
Map.addLayer(pasture.select('pasture_2018'),{min:0,max:1},'raster2018') // last band with displacement

Map.addLayer(table,{},'vector2018') //original vector for pasture_2018
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/efd3db90c2abce545ad255efa45a2329

In the example above all the bands, except by the last one `pasture_2018`, are in the same `crsTransform` parameters. But the last one is different and clearly with a displacement (apparently 1 cell right and 1 to the top).

[image]

How can I fix this inside GEE? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have data whose projection is not correct, you can use the `changeProj` operation. For example, to shift your data one unit to the east as defined by its original projection, you would use it like:

```
var image = ee.Image('users/vieiramesquita/PASTAGEM3/pasture_lapig_'+yr);
var shiftedImage = image.changeProj(
    image.projection(),
    image.projection().translate(1, 0));
```

`changeProj` takes two projection parameters because its general form is to take the pixels' coordinates as they would be in *any* projection (first parameter) and reinterpret them in any other projection (second parameter); in this case I'm taking the projection that the image is already in (`image.projection()`), and modifying it as required for the purpose.

Comment: Hi Kevin, this is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!!